# How to search the text in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, web

> Hai,  we have a requirement like previewing the documents as like in
>   windows7/vista  "preview Pane" and have to implement the search
>   functionality in Winforms.For that,  I have loaded the Ms office
>   docuemnts, and Excel Sheets and Power Point documents into Webbrowser
>   Control in html format.Now we need to implement the search
>   functionality in that webbrowser Control.   For that we have
>   implemented the search functionality using the following code

```
public bool FindNext(string text, WebBrowser webBrowser1)
        {

            IHTMLDocument2 doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

            IHTMLSelectionObject sel =doc.selection;// (IHTMLSelectionObject)doc.selection;
            IHTMLTxtRange rng = sel.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;

            rng.collapse(false); // collapse the current selection so we start from the end of the previous range
            if (rng.findText(text, 1000000, 0))
            {
                rng.select();
                return true;
            }
            else
                FindFirst(text, webBrowser1);
            return false;
        }
```

> This code is working fine for searching the string values in word
>   Document for all the occurences.    But when it Comes to Excel and PPt
>   documents this code doesn't work properly.it finds only the first
>   occurrence of the string other occurrences doesn't find.   while
>   debugging i found that,for word Documents "IHTMLDocument2" object
>   stores the html Content in "innerHTML" and "innerText" with some
>   values. But for Excel it stores the text in "innerHTML" only by using
>   the Frames, and sheets are referenced to local temporary .html files
>   and it didn't have any "innerText" content it showing as null.
>
> ```
>   Please provide the solution to search the text in webbrowser control which loaded the html content, that is converted from
> ```
>
> Excel,PPT to html type and displaying in webbrowser control.
>
> If you have any queries please feel to ask me.
>
> Thank You.

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915046/how-to-implement-the-search-functionality-in-webbrowser-control-for-text-and-exc

If you have additional comments to make regarding progress you've made, add them to the previous question.

Comment: i didn't get any reply's for previous questions, i think so those questions were  not much explanatory that's why i posted my exact problem.Don't mind.